# SHGetFileInfo get access violation when I use gflags to enable page heap with flags(full unaligned traces)

Tags: c++, windows

My code is like this:

```
#include <Windows.h>

int main () {
    TCHAR path[MAX_PATH] = {0};
    GetModuleFileName(0, path, MAX_PATH);

    SHFILEINFO sfi;
    ZeroMemory(&sfi, sizeof(SHFILEINFO));
    CoInitialize(NULL);
    SHGetFileInfo(path, 0, &sfi, sizeof(SHFILEINFO), SHGFI_ICON | SHGFI_LARGEICON);

    return 0;
}
```

When I use gflags to set page heap flags like this:

> gflags.exe -p /enable FileLock.exe /unaligned

The application get the exception following:
Unhandled exception at 0x037b1a32 in FileLock.exe 0xC0000005:Access violation reading location 0x03876ff4.

But if I disable page heap with command like this:

> gflags.exe -p /disable FileLock.exe
>   Everythis will be ok.

P.S.:My OS is Windows XP 32bits. And Windows Vista 64bits get the same exception.

Comment: Which line gives you the exception?

Comment: Is the process compiled as Unicode or ANSI?  The default is Unicode, in which case the first argument needs to be a Unicode string, not an ANSI string.

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong with the code you posted - it compiles and runs without errors in debug and release using VS2012 x86 on Win8 64bit. Is this the actual code that fails, and does it still fail if you *don't* use `gflags`?

Comment: Cases in which the code can break::
1. Current Code:: error C2664: 'SHGetFileInfoW' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'char [260]' to 'LPCWSTR'
2. If you use 'SHGetFileInfoA' without changing anything else in your current code:: error C2664: 'SHGetFileInfoA' : cannot convert parameter 3 from 'SHFILEINFO *' to 'SHFILEINFOA *'
3. If you change "SHFILEINFO sfi;" to "SHFILEINFOA sfi;":: Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'sfi' was corrupted.
4. If you use 'SHFILEINFOA' everywhere including "sizeof":: SUCCESS

So, either use ANSI or UNICODE entirely. Aprt frm tht the code is gud.

Comment: It's not the problem of ANSI or UNICODE.And I have changed my bad code.It must be the problem of gflags,as if I don't use gflags,everythis is ok.

Comment: Is this code a part of some other code? Try just ANSI with 'char', 'GetModuleFileNameA', 'SHFILEINFOA' and 'SHGetFileInfoA' and see if the crash is reproducible. I have tried your code with 'gflags.exe -p /enable FileLock.exe /unaligned' and it ran fine.

Comment: @jeJee: please try rebuilding the code exactly as in the question in a new project and workspace.  The issue could be something to do with your project settings.  It would also be a good idea to try running the application on a freshly installed machine with no other software installed, in case you're seeing interference from an injected DLL.

Comment: @Harry Johnston: Thanks for your reply! The application is really crashed in an injected DLL on my computer. But when I tried running the application on Win7-64bits, it was crashed in verifier.dll, which is system DLL in SysWOW64 folder. And I have no idea why this happened.